# Word Search Program (Python)

Tags: python

I'm working on a word search program which reads a file and converts a given amount of strings in the file into a word search board alongside a list of words to search for. My program is mostly working however, I'm not sure how to find the ending location for the words in my list.

My code:

```
def print_it_out(lines, words):
    for direction, tuple in lines.items():
        string = ''.join([i[0] for i in tuple])
        for word in words:
            if word in string:
                coordinates = tuple[string.index(word)][1]
                #print(word, 'starts at', coordinates[0], 'and column', coordinates[1], direction + ".")
                print(word, 'starts at (%d, %d)' % (coordinates[0], coordinates[1]))


def find_words(file_input, words):
    with open(file_input) as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.replace(' ', '')
            line = line.strip()
            if len(line) == 0:
                for line in file:
                    line = line.replace('\n', '')
                    line = line.lower()
                    words.append(line)
    words = [x.upper() for x in words]
    words = sorted(words)
    print(words)


def get_search_board(file_input, search_board):
    with open(file_input) as file:
        for line in file:
            if len(line.strip()) == 0:
                break
            elif len(line) > 6:
                # line = line.replace('\n', '')
                line = line.lower()
                search_board += line
    search_board = search_board.rstrip()
    search_board = search_board.replace(' ', '')
    length = search_board.index('\n') + 1
    return search_board, length


def main():
    words = []
    search_board = ''
    file_input = input('Enter the name of the file that contains the word search: ')
    find_words(file_input, words)
    search_board, length = get_search_board(file_input, search_board)

    letters = [(letter, divmod(index, length))
               for index, letter in enumerate(search_board)]
    # Reorder the list to represent each reading direction,
    # and add them all to a dictionary
    lines = {}
    offsets = {'down': 0, 'right down': -1, 'left down': 1}
    for direction, offset in offsets.items():
        lines[direction] = []
        for i in range(length):
            for j in range(i, len(letters), length + offset):
                lines[direction].append(letters[j])
            lines[direction].append('\n')
    lines['left'] = letters
    lines['right'] = [i for i in reversed(letters)]
    lines['up'] = [i for i in reversed(lines['down'])]
    lines['left up'] = [i for i in reversed(lines['right down'])]
    lines['right up'] = [i for i in reversed(lines['left down'])]
    # Make strings from the letters, find the words in them and retrieve
    # their original locations

    print_it_out(lines, words)


main()
```

The given file I'm using:

```
15 15
J H C J B E H U C Y M J A L Q
N Q Q H K C B V T E X U F A E
W O T A X E J K G N B P V M D
C H C O U I R D P O F X X Z B
Q M F R C P L P B H X K S L S
H L I E A R F C Q V O H M D D
K V F V P E A S Y Q P Z O J L
H K Z N L T V G P C N G H D L
R R Z V B S H D S M X Y T L B
N A A R D A G G Q S I S D N A
O Y F W O M W E I L P X J R Z
Y D F C R W O S A U Z Y O T W
K H M E E A L N C C G X L F B
L Z F F S K Q I E L A R S S B
X Z O H P D M J W Y C V D P A

BOBCAT
CAKE
cat
easy
HONEY
MASTERPIECE
MONEY
PEASY
```

For clarification, my program is able to find each of the given words and their start locations through a coordinate, however, I also want to be able to find each word's ending/last coordinate. In addition to this, I want print out each word its corresponding coordinates in alphabetical order. If you have any advice, it's appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If you found the entire word, the length of the match is the length of the word you were searching for, no?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
from collections import Counter

file = open(r"C:/Users/rschuell/Desktop/test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
wordcount = Counter(file.read().split())
for word in file.read().split():
    if word not in wordcount:
        wordcount[word] = 1
    else:
        wordcount[word] += 1
print (word,wordcount)
file.close();
for item in wordcount.items(): print("{}\t{}".format(*item))
```