# How to code a word search program in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

1st problem coordinate 'compiler':

I am practically a newbie in python, and I was tasked to create a word search program in python. As of now I can find the coordinates of a certain character given a board, but it finds ALL instances of the characters. A I would really appreciate some help!

2nd problem:

I tried to progress on the code to not waste time. But I have no idea how to go on. After, supposedly getting the coordinates the code must also state the word's direction (e.g right,left,down-left,up-left,down-right,up-right). I have no idea on I would get this. I was thinking about using slope to determine  the direction but I have been running around circles on how exactly  I would be translating this into a python code. Thank you so much in advance for your help!

I have already tried restricting to having only one character taken per row, but I realize this won't do since multiple words can be in the same row. Really hit a dead end here.

So basically this is the section that gets the coordinates of the first letter of the given 'words' in the board.

```
words=['row', 'war', 'raw','rar','dew','rod','red']
rows= ['rar', 'aoe', 'wed',]#rows in the board

for row_number, row in enumerate(rows):
    for column_number, letter in enumerate(row):
        for word in words:
                if word[0]==letter:
                    print(letter,(column_number+1,row_number+1))
```

1st problem:

The code gives me an output of:

```
r (1, 1)
r (1, 1)
r (1, 1)
r (1, 1)
r (1, 1)
r (3, 1)
r (3, 1)
r (3, 1)
r (3, 1)
r (3, 1)
w (1, 3)
d (3, 3)
```

As could see the coordinates are really not that helpful. It seems that it just keep finding the same letter again and again How would I fix this?

2nd problem:

I was hoping to produce the output:

```
word(x,y)-direction
```

The (x,y) coordinate is somehow almost done and I think I can store the solutions the only problem left now is how I would determine the direction.
Thanks again for the help!

Comment: for your first problem it seems like you simply need to loop the first row only. Your last `T` is printed because the first `T` of `TEA` is matched against the last `T` of `SIT`. And to your second problem, isn't the direction always down?

Comment: THANK YOU! I'll try it right away and I'll get back to you for the 1st problem. For the 2nd problem, yes in that case its all down but I only inputted that kind of board to simplify the process during coding. The words can go in all directions when my professor would check it.

Comment: I would suggest using regular expressions. Here is the documentation https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions You can use the re.findall() function which is used for finding text

Comment: @Tomerikoo, Tried doing as you said but it won't do since the first letters can also be in any part of the board. My apologies for having a bad example , I'll clear it up right away.

Comment: Yeah @Barb tried importing the library, but my professor is kinda against in letting us use any kind of libraries. We just need to find another way around for it.

Comment: Well, your code seems to be fine... It prints whenever it matches a first letter of a word with the letter in the board. You are just checking for the first letter so I don't understand what you expect? After finding a match on the first letter you need to go on to the next letter...

Comment: fair play to your professor. This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768206/word-search-program-python

Comment: @Tomerikoo, yes but is it okay that the code finds every instance of a certain letter? If so how would I then determine its direction. My apologies really, being a 1 month old programming student can really be daunting

Comment: @Barb, hmmm interesting but the part below the offset dictionary does not ring any bell for me can you explain it in more simpler terms to me?

Comment: I am not sure this is a programming issue. You need to first analyze the problem, in the logic level, before even talking code. Your code finds now matches of first letter so in my point of view it seems that your code is fine. Just broken in the middle. After finding a match on first letter you need to go on to search for the second letter in the neighbor cells and then determine the direction

Comment: The offset is just the variable name used for the directional coordinates. You can name it anything. It is set as a dictionary linking the word to a key using the semi colon. Beneath that the offset dictionary words that are paired to the key used to coordinate through the grid in the x and y direction with forward and reverse. So the word will be identified in each direction for its full length